# Load bit data type data from SQL to Numeric data type in Oracle - SSIS

Tags: ssis

Hi,

I am trying to load data from SQL table which is bit data type for one of the column in to Oracle table where column data type is numeric and all the values of  1 are loading as -1 in Oracle table. Please let me know the solution as I tried to convert but didn't work as expected.

SQL     Database:- Column Name - Is Load; Data Type: Bit           ; Values- 1,0

Oracle Database:- Column Name: - IsLoad; Data Type - Numeric; Values - ( Need 1,0 but loading -1 instead of 1 )

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use a `Derived Column` transformation to explicitly convert to numeric:

[image]

In this case I'm converting [MakeFlag] column, which is type bit, into a numeric(9,0). When is true 1, when is false 0, with the expression

```
(DT_NUMERIC,9,0)(MakeFlag ? 1 : 0)
```

The new column is [Derived Column 1], which can now be loaded into an Oracle numeric column.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sandeep You're welcome, I'm happy to help. Please accept the  answer/vote up if this has solved the problem.